# Dynamic Data Type of Parameters in Stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table `Customer` which has 3 columns

```
CCode varchar(100),
CName varchar(200),
Address varchar(500)
```

I want to create a procedure to insert data, I want that datatype of parameter should be selected automatically according to the table columns, so that for example if i need to change the `CCode` datatype from varchar to int in the table, it should be automatically change the datatype of parameter `CCode`.

Like oracle provide % type attribute, as you can see in below link:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/type_attribute.htm

I want same functionality as mentioned in above link.

Comment: Probably use [`sql_variant`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173829.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't support the %TYPE functionality that Oracle has. You could use `sql_variant`, but that has drawbacks around knowing what type it's supposed to be. You could also try having a variety of optional parameters, and then using whichever is actually going to be used in your situation.